# Map database and Model in Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dapper

**My database:**

```
uId | uName | uAge | uAddress
```

**Model:**

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public int Name {get; set;}
public int Age {get; set;}
public int Address {get; set;}
```

**Query:**

```cs
public User GetUserById(int userId)
{
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.Value.ConnectionString))
   {
       var param = new DynamicParameters();
       param.Add("@userID", userId);
       return con.Query("GetuserDetails", param, null, true, 0, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
   }
}
```

Is there any way that I can map these?

On the other side I tried to change my property as per DB and used `JsonProperty` in the annotation,

```cs
[JsonProperty("Name")]
public string uName { get; set; }
```

But after consuming the data in the client and converting back to `User` object will it throws null again. I can't change the column name in the DB as that will be the standard and I wanted the property name to be clean (Name, Age) too.

Any help? Am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create a constructor with the names of the columns and the correct types. Assuming you are on SQL-Server, it would be the following:

```
public class User
{
   public User(int uId, string uName, int uAge, string uAddress)
   {
      Id = uId;
      Name = uName;
      Age = uAge;
      Address = uAddress;
   }
}
```

Now you can change the sql-query invocation to this:

```
return con.Query<User>("GetuserDetails", param, null, true, 0, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
```

Now Dapper is able to map them to your class because it finds a constructor matching to the column- names and types. If you need an empty constructor as well, just add one without any parameters.

Comment: Got this idea but I have some 50 properties, is there any elegant / simple way to do this?

Comment: No, not with Dapper alone. You can auto-generate a constructor though. You would still need to change the parameter names. You could use Entity-Framework instead and scaffold the Db-Context. Still requires lots of manual work after for renaming properties of the model that has been scaffolded.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [ColumnAttributeTypeMapper](https://gist.github.com/senjacob/8539127)?

```cs
[Column("uId")]
public int Id {get; set;}
[Column("uName")]
public int Name {get; set;}
[Column("uAge")]
public int Age {get; set;}
[Column("uAddress")]
public int Address {get; set;}
```